# 2013 Audi A6 3.0T Quattro PP

Tags: oil, audi, oil-pan, a6

I see the car dreeping oil on my driveway. But on the top I cant see anything leaking. On the bottom I cant pinpoint the exact location. So I put some dye to maybe see it coming out. But still cant pinpoint the location exactly. With out a lift is very difficult to do see. I even use a fish-cam but nothing. Any knows the most common oil leaks for this engine and where I should focus?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you clean the area of the bottom of your car before you started looking at the dye?